# Why I'm getting exception UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 6 errors and how to fix it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, build-error

I have unity3d editor version : 2018.4.5f1 Personal

When I'm doing : File > Buil Settings... then Build or File > Build And Run I'm getting after 1-2 seconds exceptions :

First :

> Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Then :

> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 6 errors
>     at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00242] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:194 
>     at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:97 
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

A screenshot of the building window :

[image: Building settings window]

Tried to google, I don't have any plugin/s folder in the Assets as someone suggested to delete.
Someone else suggested : "use legacy SDK tools" (player settings >> publishing settings" But I can't find anywhere in the editor the publishing settings.

Maybe I should download and update to the latest unity editor version ?

Comment: Tried to update the unity editor to the latest version now only when clicking the Build And Run it's giving the exception. Not even showing the building window.

Comment: Try to find out that **6 errors** from the editor log file.

Comment: I tried now new empty clean project and I can build it no problems. But in my project with the main menu and I have another loaded with many objects scene I have the problem when trying to build. I tried to look in the Hierarchy and didn't see any problems. I can run the game without and problems no errors no exceptions. The exception is show only when trying to build.

Comment: I can see the 6 exceptions/errors but when double click to get to the scripts with the visual studio there are no errors like it says in the editor.  Everything is exist and fine and I can build it in the visual studio.  But in the editor it says there are errors.

Comment: For example : Assets\My Scripts\AutocompleteSearchField\AutocompleteSearch.cs(4,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'IMGUI' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEditor' (are you missing an assembly reference?) But when I'm getting to the script I see the 'IMGUI' amd don't get any errors.

Comment: You may add these errors in the question too. (and AutocompleteSearch.cs if possible)

Comment: `UnityEdtior` namespace and its assemblies are inavailable when build.

Comment: I fixed this errors by deleting this two scripts I'm not using and was for testing and playing around. Now it's all working fine. Thanks and sorry for the troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you don't have a blank script who connect each other script and make sure you don't have an error on your script like missing reference etc, try to update your unity
this only my opinion because if I'm getting an error that must be from the script, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: This is strange now I see that it is missing in the On Value Change () event of a button but when I drag the Canvas with the script and then select the function it's not giving me the option to select the see in this link for screenshot it has the function SetQuality(int) but not the Dynamic int SetQuality strange.  https://imgur.com/a/1PDk0Dc

Answer (score 3):

I also struggled with this, but the following fixed it for me:

1. Run a search through your entire codebase for "UnityEditor".
2. Any script that references "UnityEditor" must either be inside a folder called "Editor", or must have all references of "UnityEditor" wrapped in pre-compile flags to exclude them from a build.
3. By pre-compile flag, I mean something like "#if UNITY_EDITOR" / "#endif".

From this link: https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-build-errors.663364/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I went to Canvas, (2D Game) selected the animation which was causing the issues, Score. Clicked on Motion and select `None`. The selected value was `Blender`, I don't understand why. That solved all the issues.